# Hide/unhide rows when clicking on a cell in a given range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to hide and unhide rows when clicking in a range.

Here are the ranges and respective rows:

Range("A1:L1")
Rows("2:11")

Range("A12:L12")
Rows("13:23")

Range("A24:L24")
Rows("25:34")

I am unable to find this scenario in code. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Google "Worksheet_SelectionChange() Event"

Comment: I need to see an example of at least two ranges if selected then hide respective rows (or unhide if already hidden).

Comment: The first result of that google search shows examples of using that event in VBA. The idea of StackOverflow is that we will _help_ you if you have a programming problem - but you must show what you have researched and tried for yourself. No one will simply write the code for you.

Comment: Yes, I read it and about 15 other posts/articles. I used SelectionChange() Event . If Intersect ActiveCell is nothing then exit sub else hide rows. Hung up with multiples of these ranges and also with hiding rows accordingly. Was unsure how to approach further questions. Hoping it would come about through constructive conversation such as this as well as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'd use grouping for this case instead a VBA macro. However, add this code to your Worksheet class:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Rows("2:11").Hidden Then Rows("2:11").Hidden = True
    If Not Rows("13:23").Hidden Then Rows("13:23").Hidden = True
    If Not Rows("25:34").Hidden Then Rows("25:34").Hidden = True

    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:L1")) Is Nothing
            Rows("2:11").Hidden = False

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("A12:L12")) Is Nothing
            Rows("13:23").Hidden = False

        Case Not Intersect(Target, Range("A24:L24")) Is Nothing
            Rows("25:34").Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought to use select case.